# Need help using a foreach to increment a number in swift ui

Tags: swift, foreach, swiftui

```
ForEach(self.thingobserved.things){ i in
If self.data == i.something {
Count+= 1
}
}
```

> this is my code and everytime I put this code it tells me

“unable to infer complex closure return type; 
add explicit type to disambiguate”

Comment: You might be confusing SwiftUI's ForEach (a type of View), witch something like Collection's forEach.  You wouldn't want to mutate a value in the body of a ForEach view, because that would run every time your view hierarchy gets re-rendered.  Are you trying to create some view here, or just trying to increment a number in a collection?

Comment: It doesn't really work like that. `ForEach` isn't like a `for` loop. It's a function that sets up an association between a collection of items, and the view contents necessary to display that. When the view refreshes, nothing says that the `ForEach` loop must loop over all element, like a `for` loop would. Instead, it could get smart and only redraw (re-run the body) for those members of `self.thingsobserved` that have changed since the last evaluation.

Comment: Yes I am only trying to increment that number, I am not trying to create any view but I would just like to know how I could fix this error that I am having

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're trying to do just isn't related to create some View, since ForEach is a type of View.

A `for` loop should suffice for what you're trying to do.

```
for item in self.thingsObserved.things {
    if self.data == item.something {
        count += 1
    }
}
```